# The apphelper file is not found on cakephp but it exists

Tags: cakephp

I had my cakephp project working fine until I made a copy of a  few files and now I get this     error.
  I checked the folders and they should not have a

1)class helper should not be in the same folder of apphelper
   2)helper should not be in the same folder as form helper with my version of cakephp.

These errors dont make sense so how do I fix this?

The errors are listed here

```
http://182.160.156.223/~aptutori/crm/users/login
```

Comment: I think you'll need to share a little more detail about the error you're getting (your link is broken, and you shouldn't post a link anyway, post it here), the way you're trying to implement the helper and where the files are in stored currently in your project.

Comment: Ok the link worked eventually. My core Helper class is located in `/cake/libs/view/helper.php` - have you moved yours from the default location on installing CakePHP?

Comment: ok it works , the missing file was helper.php which got lost somehow